# Python 3.4 venv bash activate script missing

Tags: python, cygwin, python-venv

I'm trying to create a python virtual env with the following command:

```
python -m venv myenv
```

The `Scripts` directory of the newly created `myenv` directory ends up containing the following activate scripts:

- activate.bat
- Activate.ps1

But it does not contain a bash `activate` script as I expected it to.
I'm unable to run the `activate.bat` script in cygwin - batch syntax is not accepted:

```
line 1: @echo: command not found
line 3: rem: command not found
...
```

I suggest it might be linked to my python version which is 3.4 since the bash `activate` script is created when I try to do the same thing with Python 3.7

Any tips for getting it to work with Python 3.4 ?

Comment: It seems your python is NOT the cygwin one as `$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.4` so you need to run the activate.bat from CMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Python 3.4` actually does not support venv properly. I updated to `Python 3.6.7` to get the bash `activate` script.